# URL for image files are null while executing jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, imageicon

**DISCLAIMER:** I know there are multiple answers already to this question, and I've tried those applicable to my case. The reason I am asking it again is because they didn't work.

I have some images to show in my application. The images are in the build path in Eclipse, and are **working fine** with the code below on **launching from Eclipse**:

```
// The code sits in the class "ui.IconCreater"
// The code is invoked with a sample value: pathToImageFile = "DS.png"
URL imgURL = IconCreator.class.getResource("../" + pathToImageFile);
if(imgURL != null)
    return new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imgURL), altText);
else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find the specified icon file: " + pathToImageFile);
```

I am using the **Runnable Jar** option in Eclipse for exporting my application. I can verify, using the Archive Manager, that the image files have been extracted to the specific location they are supposed to be. A screenshot of the contents of the jar is below.
[image]
The contents of the manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ weka.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: ui.PUTWb
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

The error I am getting, when **running my jar**, which I cannot figure out the reason for is:
[image]
Can someone help me figure out what is wrong here?

I am using **OpenJDK8** on **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04**.

Comment: The basic idea of the solution is to "search" for the file within the CLASSPATH, instead of providing the exact location of the file. It works in my case !